# Querying more than one condition for sub array kind of document with $where

Tags: mongodb, mongo-java

I have a document which looks like this:

```
{
  "_id" : ObjectId("50a8240b927d5d8b5891743c"),
  "cust_id" : "abc",
  "ord_date" : ISODate("2012-10-03T18:30:00Z"),
  "status" : "A",
  "price" : 25,
  "items" : [
    {
      "sku" : "mmm",
      "qty" : 5,
      "price" : 2.5
    },
    {
      "sku" : "nnn",
      "qty" : 5,
      "price" : 2.5
    }]
}
```

now I want to query using `$where` for all items whose `"qty">5` and `"sku"=='mmm'`,

```
I tried the following
{
   "$where" : "this.items.some(function(entry){return entry.qty>5})&&this.items.some(function(entry){return entry.sku=='ggg'})
}
```

but it dosen't work. I want to do it only by using "$where"

Answer (score 1):

Using `$where` you can create a for loop with an `if` where you will set the conditions. It will return `true` if the conditions are satisfied:

```
db.col_t.find(
   { 
      $where: "for (var i = 0; i < this.items.length; ++i) { if (this.items[i].sku === 'mmm' && this.items[i].qty > 5) return true; }"
   }).pretty();
```

Or shorter putting the value of `$where` directly, like bellow:

```
db.col_t.find("for (var i = 0; i < this.items.length; ++i) { if (this.items[i].sku === 'mmm' && this.items[i].qty > 5) return true; }").pretty();
```

---

I recommend you to use `$elemMatch` and `$gt` this way:

Query:

```
{
   items: {
     $elemMatch: {
        qty: { $gt: 5 },
        sku: "mmm"
     }
   }
}
```

Warning: This query will not retrieve your document because using `$gt` it will search for numbers bigger (`>`) than `5`. Use `$gte` if you want `>=`.

---

References:

### `$elemMatch`

> The $elemMatch operator matches **more than one component within an array** element
>
> [**read more**](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/elemMatch/)

### `$gte`

> **Syntax**: `{field: {$gte: value} }`
>
> `$gte` selects the documents where the value of the field is **greater than or equal** to (i.e. `>=`) a specified value (e.g. value.)
>
> [**read more**](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/gte/)

### `$gt`

> **Syntax**: `{field: {$gt: value} }`
>
> `$gt` selects those documents where the value of the field is **greater than** (i.e. >) the specified value.
>
> [**read more**](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/gt/)

Comment: I want to go with $where

Comment: @PhalguniMukherjee Can you tell the reason why you want to use `$where`?

Comment: I am making a interface to the database where the user want to send query like sql "where val1>1&&val2<4||val3<5" somthing of this kind, so parsing of such string becomes easy with where, else lot of permutation and combination.

Comment: @PhalguniMukherjee If you want your users to be able to interface with the database via some structured query language, perhaps look at using a database which already supports it. :)